# renewalCount() function in Countr

Tags: regression

I'm trying to use "renewalCount" function from "Countr" package. I get the error:

```
"Error in order(-value, xtimes) : object 'xtimes' not found"
```

for the last line and I do not know how to solve it. I tried defining a vector of equal values of length 9 or 33 (sum of numb), it didn't work. Thank you very much in advance!

```
library("Countr")<br/>
library("dplyr")<br/>
library("xtable")<br/>
D=matrix(c(1:9))<br/>
Numb=matrix(c(15, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))<br/>
Number=data.frame(Numb)<br/>
a_weib <- renewalCount(formula = D ~ 1, data = Number, dist = "weibull", computeHessian = FALSE, control = renewal.control(trace = 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to install the previous CRAN version of optimx, since this error
is caused by version 2018-7.10 of optimx. After doing that, your example works:

```
packageDescription("optimx")$Version
## [1] "2013.8.7"

library("Countr")
library("dplyr")
D = matrix(c(1:9))
Numb = matrix(c(15, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))
Number = data.frame(Numb)
a_weib <- renewalCount(formula = D ~ 1, data = Number, dist = "weibull",            
     computeHessian = FALSE, control = renewal.control(trace = 0))

a_weib

## Call:
## renewalCount(formula = D ~ 1, data = Number, dist = "weibull", 
##    control = renewal.control(trace = 0), computeHessian = FALSE)
## Count model coefficients (inter-arrival weibull with scale: link log, shape:     link log):
## scale_   shape_  
## 1.3438  -0.2194  
## 
## Log-likelihood: -21.2192 on 2 Df
```

If this is a bug in package Countr, we will release a fixed version.

Comment: The issue is indeed in optimx() (on Windows it returns a data frame with column xtime instead of xtimes). The development version of Countr, see https://github.com/GeoBosh/Countr, now has a patch for it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

simply type (for R in Windows)

xtimes<-1

because xtimes works only for Linux